# Перераспределить точки между списками в Python по условию

Tags: python, list, итераторы

Имеется список со списками (больше двух), в которых даны координаты точек:

Задача заключается в том, чтобы сравнить координаты точек одного списка с координатами точек другого списка, и, если хотя бы одна точка одного из списков будет находиться на расстоянии ближе чем 0.1 по отношению к точке другого списка, то эту точку и все другие точки этого списка, нужно перенести в список точки, с которой происходило сравнение.

Например:

[[(0.8, 0.7), (0.1, 0.1)], [(0.2, 0.9), (0.8, 0.1)], [(0.1, 0.1), (0.5, 0.5)]]

В первом и последнем списке есть точки с одинаковыми координатами, значит они будут удовлетворять условию, тогда результатом проверки будет список следующего вида:

[[(0.8, 0.7), (0.1, 0.1), (0.1, 0.1), (0.5, 0.5)], [(0.2, 0.9), (0.8, 0.1)]]

Comment: интересно, а если будет 0, 0.1, 0.2 - тогда все собрать вместе или только первые два?

Comment: Велико ли общее количество точек?

Comment: Что именно вызвало у вас затруднение в этой задаче? Распишите задачу по шагам и реализуйте. Где будут затруднения - спрашивайте.

Comment: @splash58, если снова будет группа с точками, где хотя бы одна удовлетворит условию, то ее тоже добавить в первый список, то есть ситуация, когда в итоге получится всего лишь одна группа с точками, тоже возможна

Comment: @MBo, обычно общее количество групп точек от 5 до 10, в каждой группе порядка 75-100 тысяч точек

Comment: запускаете multiprocessing и считаете все сочетания, берете минимумы для каждой пару списков, собираете те, которые удовлетворяют условию. возможно процесс надо повторять до тех пор, пока будет хоть одно объединение

Comment: @CrazyElf, так и делаю, но решение получается каким-то не оптимизированным. Я сначала с помощью combinations в цикле создаю пары групп, потом с помощью product в цикле комбинации точек для сравнения. А дальше не знаю, как делать лучше. Если находится решение, то по идее надо остановить итерирование, найденный элемент вернуть, исключить из одного списка, вставить в другой вместе с другими элементами, и продолжить итерирование. На словах решение как бы есть, а фактически реализовать не получается, к сожалению.

Comment: Охо-хо... Если дело разовое, то можно искать все расстояния за квадратичное время и далее объединять union-find.    Если списки меняются, то простыми средствами не обойдёшься, нужно будет строить какие-то геометрические структуры данных (и тут главное, чтобы это построение не вышло дольше основной работы)

Comment: Есть ли особенности - например, списки - это точки на полилиниях?

Comment: Это порядка 10 миллиардов проверок что ли получается только для двух групп. Многовато. Хотя это в худшем случае. Если досрочно встретится нужная точка, то может всё гораздо быстрее будет. Если нормально досрочное окончание сделать. И не превращать генераторы/итераторы в реальные списки. А вообще это очень похоже на задачу кластеризации. Так может лучше взять какой-то готовый алгоритм кластеризации и не мучиться? Выбрать только с подходящей метрикой. Есть и специальные алгоритмы, заточенные на миллионы точек и быстро работающие.

Comment: @CrazyElf, так и есть, это кластеризация, просто точек очень много, когда я использую алгоритм кластеризации, он жалуется на нехватку памяти, в итоге общее кол-во точек было разбито на группы, внутри каждой группы отрабатывает кластеризация. Моя задача: собрать результат кластеризации маленьких групп и объединить их. "Если нормально досрочное окончание сделать. " - Это именно то, над чем я сейчас бьюсь, потому что именно так и будет, худший случай не предвидится, попадание в условие, если оно есть, произойдет на первых десятках перебора.

Comment: @MBo, я свою задачу описал достаточно схематично, чтобы получить подсказку для возможного способа решения. В реальности у меня трехмерное поле точек, которые расположены сумбурно.

Comment: Есть специальные методы быстрой кластеризации ну очень больших данных. Я бы всё-таки попробовал что-то из них для начала https://github.com/erikbern/ann-benchmarks/ Тут как бы собраны ссылки на все такие библиотеки.

Comment: И приложите к вопросу файл с данными побольше размером, может на досуге получится попробовать код набросать.

Comment: @CrazyElf, спасибо за ссылку, надо будет посмотреть. Я пользовался scikit-learn clustering, но на большом кол-ве данных сходу не получилось. Файл, к сожалению, не могу приложить, если визуализировать его, то получатся элементы конструкции с производства.

Comment: Кстати, и в `sklearn` есть методы кластеризации, позволяющие сэкономить память и вообще ресурсы. Например можно попробовать `MiniBatchKMeans` https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.MiniBatchKMeans.html

Answer (score 0):

Для уменьшения количества проверок нужно создать какую-либо геометрическую структуру данных. При более-менее равномерном или случайном распределении точек в пространстве неплохо работает простое разделение пространства на кубики, каждая точка относится к одному кубику соответственно её координатам (`p(x,y,z)=>cube[x/L, y/L, z/L]`). Проверяются точки в одном кубике и в соседних восьми (размер куба должен быть больше допуска). При удачном выборе размера куба) количество проверок сокращается в среднем в m^2/9 раз, где m - количество кубов по одной координате.

Если распределение плохое, может понадобиться строить что-то вроде kd-tree - в этом случае для каждой точки быстро выполняется запрос о ближайшей. Вероятно, для Python есть готовые реализации.

При обнаружении близости точек из разных списков списки объединяются , вначале виртуально, с помощью метода [Union-Find](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85%D1%81%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2), по окончанию работы списки с общим представителем сливаются физически.